# Change format of knex.js json output

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, knex.js

I have this in my Node application:

```
const query = db_connect.sequelize.knex.select([
      'managers.id',
      'managers.managername',
      'managers.email',
      'teams.teamname',
      'teams.id',
      db_connect.sequelize.knex.raw('COUNT(employees_managers.id)'),
    ]).from('managers')
      .leftJoin('employees_users', 'managers.id', 'employees_managers.managers_id')
      .leftJoin('teams_managers', 'managers.id', 'teams_managers.managers_id')
      .leftJoin('teams', 'teams.id', 'teams_managers.teams_id')
      .groupByRaw('managers.id, managers.managername, managers.email, teams.teamname');
```

It produces this:

```
{
    "managers": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "John Doe",
            "email": "johndoe@email.com",
            "teamname": "Team 1",
            "count": 2
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "John Doe",
            "email": "johndoe@email.com",
            "teamname": "Team 2",
            "count": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

I'd like to change it's structure to look like this:

```
{
    "managers": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "John Doe",
            "email": "johndoe@email.com",
            "teams": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Team 1",
                    "TeamsManagers": {
                        "id": 1,
                        "managerId": 1
                    }
                },
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "Team 2",
                        "TeamsManagers": {
                            "id": 1,
                            "managerId": 1
                        }
                    }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How do I change the structure of a knex response to show it in the format above? I had tried looking at bookeself.js but not sure if  that's the correct tool for the job.

Comment: You are on the right track with Bookshelf as, being an ORM, would allow you to setup the appropriate relationships - Knex is more of a low-level SQL builder. There are [examples](https://bookshelfjs.org/#examples) demonstrating 1..* relationships.

Comment: Can I do anything on the back of a Knex query with Bookshelf though?

Comment: Bookshelf sits over the top of Knex

Comment: Ah, I think I can actually do this with `sequelize`.

Comment: yep, Sequelize is an ORM

Comment: With objection.js (also built on top of knex) query to do that would be `await Managers.query().eager('teams.TeamsManagers')`. Though you will need to setup relations to `Managers`, `Teams` models correctly to make it work. But its easy and after that you don't even have to write any joins to make it work (though that should be pretty much as easy to do also with sequelize or bookshelf if used correctly).